# Understanding how waitpid works with signals

Tags: process, signals, fork, system-calls

Consider the following Pseudo-C code:

```
static int G = 0;
void alrm_handler(int signo) {
    G = 1;
}

void son() {
    struct sched_param param;
     param.sched_priority = 50;
    sched_setscheduler(getpid(),SCHED_FIFO, &param);
    kill(getppid(), SIG_ALRM);
    sched_yield();
    printf("A\n");
    while(1);
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    signal(SIG_ALRM, alrm_handler);
    int son_pid = fork();
    if(son_pid==0)
        son();
    waitpid(son_pid);
    printf("B\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's from an exam in OS. The question is as follows:

```
In multi cores CPU what would be printed?
```

The answers is that we can't know because it could be `A` and then `B` or `B` and then `A`. I don't understand why. If parent is waiting for the son with `waitpid` and the son sends signal `SIG_ALRM` which invokes the `alrm_handler` function for the parent, the parent will finish executing the function and then return to waiting the son until he will finish running, no? So it should be `A` and then `B`.

Comment: The "son" is running an infinite loop. So it'll be A followed by nothing as "son" process runs forever.

Comment: That what I think but the answer is that we can't know. My only guess is that `waitpid` does not wait to his son to finish

Comment: Why wouldn't waitpid wait? Also note `waitpid` (rather than `wait`) has an option to *not* wait (your pseudo code doesn't help things here).

Comment: Yes I agree. I just trying to figure out what the author of the question meant. As I understand `waitpid` will wait if it gets some value.

Answer (score 0):

According to POSIX it is undefined whether system calls are restarted after a signal handler set by `signal` is called.

- System V and the Linux `signal` system call do not restart system calls.
- BSD and by default GLibc, do restart system calls.

If System V `signal` is used `waitpid` can return as soon the signal has been sent, allowing the letters to be printed in any order. If standard output is a pipe or regular file only `B` will be output as the child is in a infinite loop

With BSD `signal` only `A` will be printed as `waitpid` does not return due to the infinite loop in the child. If standard output is a pipe or regular file only nothing will be output.